# C++ simple program to count steps length

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm writing a C++ program that should show every possible combination of steps you may use when walking, given the distance to walk, number of steps to take and the maximum step length. I implemented an algorithm that works only with 2 steps, and I don't know what to do next, in order to make it work with multiple steps.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int maxsteplength, steps, distance;

    std::cin >> maxsteplength >> steps >> distance;

    //for(int i=0; i<steps; i++)
    //{
        for(int j=1; j<=maxsteplength; j++)
        {
            for(int x=1; x<=maxsteplength; x++)
            {
                if(j+x==distance) std::cout << j << " " << x << std::endl;
            }
        }
    //}
    return 0;
}
```

In this code variable *steps* doesn't even work, because it always counts all the possible ways only with two steps.
E.g. [Wrote 80 steps, but counts only with 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv921.png)

And here is an example of output that I want [maxsteplength=50, steps=2, distance=30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJFmB.png)

Thanks!

Comment: "In this code variable steps doesn't even work" .. I dont understand, In this code the variable `step` is declared and read from cin,  but then not used anywhere (besides the comment, but how can a comment "not work"?)

Comment: Well it doesn't do anything. That's what I wanted to say.

Comment: If you walk 6m and have a maxsteplength of 2m then you want the output to be `1` and `2`? If you walk 5m you want only `1`? Then why would you need the number of steps? If you want to input the number of steps, then why do you need to iterate?

Comment: Please show an example of the desired output.

Comment: @A.Hue no. I want the output to be all possible distances between steps to travel that distance.

Comment: @A.Hue e.g. [Maxsteplength - 50, steps - 2, distance - 30](http://prntscr.com/e05mkf)

Comment: My steps aren't integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to your problem, but I would suggest looking into the technique that is called recursion. Basically, it defines a problem in terms of the same problem, but with a smaller size. That way, by solving the smaller instances of the same problem one can assemble the solution for the bigger problem.

For your problem, consider a recursive solution as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void recursive_step(int maxsteplength, int steps, int distance, std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    if(steps == 0)
    {
        if(distance == 0)
        {
            std::cout << vec[0];
            for(int x = 1; x < vec.size(); x++)
            {
                std::cout << " " << vec[x];
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        return;
    }

    for(int x=(vec.size() > 0 ? vec.back() : 1); x <= maxsteplength; x++)
    {
        if(distance - x >= 0)
        {
            vec.push_back(x);
            recursive_step(maxsteplength, steps-1, distance - x, vec);
            vec.pop_back();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int maxsteplength, steps, distance;

    std::cin >> maxsteplength >> steps >> distance;
    std::vector<int> vec;
    recursive_step(maxsteplength, steps, distance, vec);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that **this solution is unbelievably inefficient** and can fail you for large input sizes, especially for large maxsteplength and large distances. I would recommend using this solution as a prototype and working on your own, better and more efficient recursive solution.

Once you got the hang of recursion, and can solve this problem using recursion, you may look into the concept of memoization and even into dynamic programming. The former can help you increase the performance of your recursive solution while the latter can present a similar, yet different solution to the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, but it sounds so difficult, maybe there's some easy way to solve my problem?

Comment: @GiedriusR. If the number of steps you can take is not specified, your loop based approach can have a hard time. Let me update my answer with a recursive solution to your problem. Note that it will be inefficient, but it may serve as a starting point for you.

Comment: Okay it works, but every step is on the new line, and I want to get an output that every possible's way's steps would be on the same line.

Comment: @GiedriusR. Do you mind checking again? I played with the format.

Comment: Well it doesn't even work as it should [you can see it here](http://prntscr.com/e05zmz)

Comment: @GiedriusR. You tried an earlier version again. The current version of the code works. You can see it [here](http://ideone.com/sVSCCA).

Comment: Great, now it works! Big thanks! I'll try to make my own now.